# OpenCV 3.0-dev for iOS

Tags: ios-frameworks, opencv3.0

I want to use the tracker (TLD tracker, MIL tracker, in particular) module in 3.0-dev, which is mentioned in the [doc](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/tracking/doc/tracking.html).

However, I can only find 3.0-alpha and 3.0-beta pre-built frameworks for iOS in sourceforge, none of which contains the tracking API I would like to use.

I am a little confused where the 3.0-dev framework is? If there is no pre-built framework for iOS, where can I find the 3.0-dev source and the instruction to build my own?

Answer (score 0):

The tracking component in OpenCV is actually located as an external component and you should specifically add it when building your OpenCV Library.

You should look at installing OpenCV [with contrib_modules](https://github.com/itseez/opencv_contrib) there is a little explanation on how to do so there.

I have succesfully managed to install it on a win10 computer running visual studio. Unfortunately, I find the implementation of TLD in OpenCV 3 insufficient : it performs very slowly compared to other tracking implementations (OpenTLD...)

Good luck !